# How to get Google plus Person's object type

Tags: java, android, google-plus

The documentation at [Android Developers page](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.html#getObjectType%28%29) states that Person.getObjectType() returns an int value as object type, but possible values are "person" and "page". How can I check if object is type of "person" or type of "page"? equals() doesn't allow to compare int with String and I have no idea how can I make that comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that the documentation does not express it well, but if you look for a little more you find that it is refering to constants, defined here (in fact there is a link from the page you posted)

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.ObjectType.html

Answer (score 1):

May you can check with [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/plus/model/people/Person.ObjectType.html) :

```
int type = getObjectType();

if(type == Person.ObjectType.PAGE)
 //this is a page
else if(type == Person.ObjectType.PERSON)
 //this is a person
```